# How can I install Anaconda in Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits to produce python programs for both 32 and 64 bits pcs?

Tags: python, ubuntu, x86, 64-bit, anaconda

Simple as the title says.

I have an `Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits` and I must be able to produce programs to be used in both 32 bits and 64 bits computers.

In `Win7 64 bits` I installed Anaconda in separate folders (`c:/anaconda_32` and `c:/anaconda_64`) and it worked perfectly.

Since I found somewhere that this was a compiler problem ( pyInstaller) I  installed Ubuntu 32 bits libraries by using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
```

But when I was installing Anaconda_x86, I received the following warning that made me think a little more about this whole process:

```
anon@anon-pc:~/Downloads$ bash Anaconda2-4.0.0-Linux-x86.sh
WARNING:
    Your system is x86_64, but you are trying to install an x86 (32-bit)
    version of Anaconda2.  Unless you have the necessary 32-bit libraries
    installed, Anaconda2 will not work.
    We STRONGLY recommend installing the x86_64 version of Anaconda2 on
    an x86_64 system.
    Are sure you want to continue the installation? [yes|no]
[no] >>>
```

So...

- How am I supposed to do this on Ubuntu without compromising the OS?
- Should I do this?
- Is installing a virtual machine my only reliable and safe option?

Answer (score 0):

I think as Anaconda installs as its own separate instance of Python (rather than replacing system Python) you'd probably be ok installing both, as long as you then provide the requisite 32bit libraries as it says.

Personally though I'd go with the safer route, keep away from your main system, and tool around in a VM instead. I've been using [Vagrant Boxes](https://www.vagrantup.com/) recently. You could have a 64 bit and 32 bit box and keep everything tidy.

Comment: Addendum: Not that I know whether it's even possible to run 32bit libraries in an Ubuntu 64bit environment.